# Specific/selected columns display in table Plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard

If I have 10 columns in my dataframe, only 5 of its require to display in my plotly table. How can I customize it?

Code:

```
@app.callback(
Output('table', 'data'), 
Input('date_dd', 'value')
)


def update_table(selection):
if len (selection) == 0:
    return dash.no_update

else:    
    dff = df[df['Settlement_Date'] == selection]  
    columns=[{'name': i, "id": i} for i in dff.columns]
    data=dff.to_dict('records')

    return data
```

Had try:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'data'), 
    Input('date_dd', 'value')
    )


def update_table(selection):
    if len (selection) == 0:
        return dash.no_update

    else:    
        dff = df[df['Settlement_Date'] == selection]          
        columns = [{'name': i, "id": i} for i in dff.loc[:,['Columns1','Columns2','Columns3','Columns4','Columns5']]]
        data=dff.to_dict('records')
    
    return data
```

Please advise.

Comment: Is this not good enough? `dff=dff[['Columns1','Columns2','Columns3','Columns4','Columns5']]`

Comment: Got it. Thanks of sharing the workaround.